# Performance in rlike expression or alternate query?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, date

I am doing a series of updates on some tables after I import them from tab-separated values. The data comes with dates in a format I do not like. I bring them in as strings, manipulate them so that they are in the same format as MySQL dates and then convert the column. Or sometimes not, but I want them to be like MySQL dates even if they are strings.

They start out like '1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM' or '11/4/2012 2:37:45 PM'.

I turn these into '2013-01-04' (usually, since times are present even when the original schema clearly specifies dates only) and '2012-11-04 14:37:45'.

I am using rlike. And this does not use indexes? Wow. That sucks.

But already, for each column, I have to use 4 updates to handle the different cases ('1/7', '2/13', '11/2', '12/24'). If I did these using like, it might take 16 different updates for each column....

And, if I am seeing it right, I cannot even get positional parameters out of the rlike expression, yes? You know, the part of the expression wrapped in parentheses that becomes $1 or $2....

So, it seems as though it is going to be quicker to pre-process the tsv file with perl. Really? Wow. Again, this sucks.

Any other suggestions? I cannot have this taking 3 hours every time I need to pull in the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the classic 1997 quote from Jamie Zawinski:

> [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions."
>
>   Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Have you tried using [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)? This is exactly for parsing nonstandard date/time strings into canonical datetime values.

If you try parsing with STR_TO_DATE() and the string doesn't match the expected format, the function returns NULL.

So you could try parsing in different formats, and return the first one that gives a non-null result.

```
UPDATE mytable
SET datecolumn = COALESCE(
    STR_TO_DATE(stringcolumn, '%m/%d'),
    STR_TO_DATE(stringcolumn, '%d/%m/%Y'),
    ...etc.
);
```

I can't tell what your different cases are. It might or might not be possible to cover all cases in one pass.

Another alternative is as you say, preprocess the raw data with Perl before you load it into MySQL. But even then, don't fight with regular expressions, use [Date::Parse](http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/TimeDate-2.30/lib/Date/Parse.pm) instead.

Comment: Well, I wish the str_to_date() function was not so slow also. It is taking 4 minutes and 29.5 seconds to update 8,143,764 records. I guess it would make sense that an index on that string would not really speed anything up. I wonder if there is a way to make str_to_date faster. I need more RAM on this machine, but I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: Try it with Perl and Date::Parse and see if it's faster to preprocess the raw data into proper MySQL date format.